# so I was making a simple calculator in python everything is working but I can't exit the loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
class Number:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __add__(self, num1):
        return self.num + num1

    def __sub__(self, num1):
        return self.num - num1

    def __mul__(self, num1):
        return self.num * num1

    def __truediv__(self, num1):
        return self.num / num1

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        while True:
            print(f"for addition press +\nfor subraction press -\nfor multiplication press *\nfor division press /\n for exit press q")
            c = input("What do you wana use: ")
            a = int(input("Number: "))
            b = int(input("Number: "))
            num = Number(a)
            num1 = Number(b)
            c = input("What do you wana use: ")
            
            if c == "+":
                sum = a + b
                print(sum)
            
            elif c == "-":
                sub = a - b
                print(sub)

            elif c == "*":
                multiply = a * b
                print(multiply)

            elif c == "/":
                divide = a / b
                print(divide)

            else:
                if c == "q":
                    print("Thank You Have a great day ahead!")
                    exit()
```

Comment: if you enter `q` you should be quitting the program (and by extension exiting the loop) just fine. Is that not working? You can type `break` as a single statement to immediately exit whatever loop you're currently in.

Comment: are you sure it's not the second "            c = input("What do you wana use: ")
" that's tripping you up?
working fine with me

Answer (score 0):

Try using `break` in the place where you want to exit the loop.